# Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Qstd=c99'

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, caffe

I have compiled caffe using VS2013 in windows following the README from[enter link description here](https://github.com/Microsoft/caffe) and I have succeeded to make my pycaffe.

After that, I try to build a faster-rcnn by python in windows. Here's the code I got:[enter link description here](https://github.com/MrGF/py-faster-rcnn-windows). but when I 'python setup.py install' in the filepath. It shows a lot of errors and warning.

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\IronDroid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Here's log, Could someone help me to point out where the error is.

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing fast_rcnn.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to fast_rcnn.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to fast_rcnn.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'fast_rcnn.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'fast_rcnn.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_ext
skipping 'utils\bbox.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'nms\cpu_nms.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
skipping 'pycocotools\_mask.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
C:\Users\IronDroid\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ipycocotools -IC:\Anaconda2\include -IC:\Anaconda2\PC /Tcpycocotools\maskApi.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\pycocotools\maskApi.obj /Qstd=c99
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/Qstd=c99'
maskApi.c
d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(31) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'intersect'
d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(31) : error C2081: '_bool' : name in formal parameter list illegal
d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(31) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'intersect'
d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(31) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(31) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'R'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(16) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'rleInit'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(25) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'rleFree'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(29) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(44) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(45) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2065: 'k' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2065: 'j' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2065: 'k' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(46) : error C2297: '*' : illegal, right operand has type 'byte *'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(49) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'intersect'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(49) : error C2081: '_Bool' : name in formal parameter list illegal
pycocotools\maskApi.c(49) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'intersect'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(49) : error C2059: syntax error : ';'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(49) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(49) : error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)
pycocotools\maskApi.c(70) : error C2059: syntax error : '}'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(77) : error C2065: '_Bool' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(77) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'crowd'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(77) : error C2065: 'crowd' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(82) : error C2065: 'crowd' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2275: 'siz' : illegal use of this type as an expression
        d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(11) : see declaration of 'siz'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ka'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'ka' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'kb' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2275: 'uint' : illegal use of this type as an expression
        d:\study\pedestrian recognition\code\py-faster-rcnn-master\lib\pycocotools\maskApi.h(10) : see declaration of 'uint'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'c'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'c' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'ca' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'cb' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'ct' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'u' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: '_Bool' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'va'
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'va' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(84) : error C2065: 'vb' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(85) : error C2065: 'ca' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(85) : error C2065: 'ka' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(85) : error C2065: 'va' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(85) : error C2065: 'vb' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'cb' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'kb' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'b' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'u' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(86) : error C2065: 'ct' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(87) : error C2065: 'ct' : undeclared identifier
pycocotools\maskApi.c(87) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
error: command 'C:\\Users\\IronDroid\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```